# I'm logged in without a password. How?

Tags: support, login, facebook

I'm new to Meta, and have registered with my Facebook account, which I use to sign in.

I notice, however, that I am automatically logged in to Meta without entering my password. How does that even work?!

> [image]

**EDIT:** Does this work when my Facebook account is deactivated? I occasionally have it deactivated, and I'd still like to be able to login to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You were logged in to Facebook already... so you didn't need to login again.

Comment: But how can i logged in, without my facebook account ( if i'm harry , i can't open my facebook account but i want to login in stackoverflow )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

That's the magic - you don't need to create *yet another* account; you can simply use your Facebook account here. Or Google, or Yahoo, or any other OpenID provider. If you're logged into your OpenID provider, you're also logged in here.

If you want to also be able to log in a different way, just go to your profile and click "my logins" in the upper right, just above your "about me" box.

Comment: But how can i logged in without my facebook account ( if i'm harry , i can't open my facebook account but i want to login in stackoverflow )?

Comment: @ZACK What do you mean? You have to log into your Facebook account if you want to log in to SO now.

Comment: Sometimes i desactivate my facebook account , and i need to login to stackoverflow, this is my problem :/

Comment: @ZACK You can add an additional non-Facebook login to your account [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add).